# starting a scene with a node paused

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I am working on a iOS game based on the nice couple `SpriteKit` and `Swift`. Targeting from iOS 7.1

The way I have implemented short sounds in the game is by running actions using `SKAction.playSoundFileNamed` method that is executed on a plain Layer-Node specially added for that purpose:

```
let SoundsLayerNode = SKNode()

self.addChild(SoundsLayerNode)

SoundsLayerNode.runAction(soundXXX)
```

Its really easy to silence the FX sounds by pausing the whole Node (`SoundsLayerNode.paused = true`), and to turn on the sounds again, unpausing the Node (`SoundsLayerNode.paused = false`)

The problem appears when I try to start the scene with the Node paused. Inside the func `didMoveToView` method I set `SoundsLayerNode.paused = true` but after the first `Spritekit` loop starts, the Node is automatically unpaussed

It seems, `SpriteKit` forces the Scene (self) to unpause  after the `didmovetoview` is finished, and all of its descendants are consequently unpaussed, triggering the unpleasant side-effect on the sound layer Node

Do you know how to sort it out?

Thanks

Comment: Try adding this `runAction (SKAction.runBlock{self.SoundsLayerNode.paused = true}) ` to `didMoveToView`

Comment: I am afraid it does not work since the problem takes place after the end of the first rendering loop (or the beginning of the second loop). If I run an Action in  didMoveToView, it is executed in the first -didEvaluateAction method that is before the 'unpause' effect is triggered

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A solution is to run an SKAction on the node to pause it after a certain amount of time (such as 0.1 seconds).

```
var pauseAction = SKAction.sequence([SKAction.wait(forDuration: 0.1), SKAction.pause()])
node.run(pauseAction)
```

You can play around with the 0.1 and see how low you can make it for it to still work.

If that doesn't work, you can do a work around like this in your GameScene:

```
var pauseToggle = true

override func didFinishUpdate() 
   {
        if(pauseToggle){
          SoundsLayerNode.paused = true
          pauseToggle = false
        }
   }
```

That's kind of a trash way of doing it but that should also work.

Comment: Second option still fails. I don't know why in the first rendering loop I can't pause a Node. It seems it is necessary to pass over the second loop. Maybe I can try something like a counter and set SoundsLayerNode.paused = true when counter ==2. But I don`t like this option very much

Comment: @Codediver Fails as in the node becomes unpaused still? And yes I agree that's a nasty way of doing it even with a boolean.  Perhaps there is somewhere else you are unpausing the node without knowing it. Is your GameScene code short enough to put into your post?

Comment: MarshallD, Did you have a chance to read my new post? I ran a simple test and checked that the testNode is automatically unpaused at the end of the first loop. I am a bit confused.

Answer (score 0):

The code is quite long, but I tried a simple test GameScene so you can take a look at the results shown in the console if I run the app for a while:

Inside didMoveToView
testNode is paused: true
scene(self) is paused: false

Loop_Update: 0
testNode is paused: true
scene(self) is paused: false

Loop_didEvaluateActions: 0
testNode is paused: true
scene(self) is paused: false

Loop_didFinishUpdate: 0
testNode is paused: true
scene(self) is paused: false

Loop_Update: 1
testNode is paused: false
scene(self) is paused: false

Loop_didEvaluateActions: 1
testNode is paused: false
scene(self) is paused: false

Loop_didFinishUpdate: 1
testNode is paused: false
scene(self) is paused: false

Does spritekit force the scene to unpause itself after the first rendering loop?

```
//
//  Test on paused Nodes
//

import SpriteKit


class GameScene: SKScene {

    let testNode = SKNode()
    var loopCounter:Int = 0


    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

    self.addChild(testNode)
    testNode.paused = true

    print ("Inside didMoveToView")
    print("testNode is paused:",testNode.paused)
    print("scene(self) is paused:",scene!.paused)
    print("")

}

override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    print ("Loop_Update:",loopCounter)
    print("testNode is paused:",testNode.paused)
    print("scene(self) is paused:",scene!.paused)
    print("")

}

override func didEvaluateActions() {

    print ("Loop_didEvaluateActions:",loopCounter)
    print("testNode is paused:",testNode.paused)
    print("scene(self) is paused:",scene!.paused)
    print("")

}

override func didFinishUpdate() {

    // This is the last chance to make changes to the scene

    print ("Loop_didFinishUpdate:",loopCounter)
    print("testNode is paused:",testNode.paused)
    print("scene(self) is paused:",scene!.paused)
    print("")

    loopCounter=loopCounter+1

}

// After didFinishUpdate SKView renders the scene. 
// Does spritekit force the scene to unpause itself here?
```

}

Comment: Based on what you have here, it looks like you are correct that the node becomes unpaused at the end. If there is a method that is called after didMoveToView then I am unaware of it. The best solution is to work around it - I have an idea involving an SKAction that gets called one time after around 0.5 seconds - would you like me to add that to my answer?

Comment: Yes, it really occurs at the end of the first rendering loop. I hope someone may know the reason. Please, add your code, it sounds interesting and I´d like to rate your help

Comment: Thanks. You found a solution to the problem. Your code gives me errors but I rewrite it based on your solution:     runAction (SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.1), SKAction.runBlock{self.SoundsLayerNode.paused = true}]))

Comment: Waiting for 0.1 seconds in the first SKAction is short enough, I supposed every rendering loop lasts 0.0166 seconds (1/60 seconds at 60fps), so 0.02s should be also short enough, 0.1 works fine :)